# maven-dependency-plugin: failure while fetching its dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy the dependencies to another location however, it fails on a checksum validation when retrieving transitive dependencies specifically `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-30`  from a private nexus server.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) on project myapp: Execution copy-dependencies of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-30: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-30 from/to mycompany.nexus (http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/groups/public): Checksum validation failed, expected aa1efeb7ed05a3c5037cc194b9e8fbf97e52268a but is 351451aebadb3a5dfa07ea8bdf9e4e336d299054
```

I tried to force the version of the plexus-container-default dependency with no luck.
If anyone can chime in on how I can resolve this noob issue it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

This is the relevant snippet from my pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${build.dir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That seemed to be the cause `http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/groups/public): Checksum validation failed, expected aa1efeb7ed05a3c5037cc194b9e8fbf97e52268a but is 351451aebadb3a5dfa07ea8bdf9e4e336d299054` There is something wrong with your configuration/network etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35561340/3181500 Try this, it worked